# should I use singular or just default plural in labeling the 'followers'

Tags: labels, text

I have this feature in my app, whereby I display the number of followers.

I created the logic so when there are no followers or zero, it's labeled as 'follower'. Currently it also does this when there is a total count of one. If the total count reaches more than one, it displays 'followers'

Does that make sense or should I put the 'followers' label regardless of the total count is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around this problem is putting the number independently of the word. Like: *Followers (0),* etc.

Comment: you meant, use the 'followers' label by default? and ignore any logic on it regardless of the total count ?

Comment: Right, we can do that if we isolate the number from the word grammatically (using the parenthesis or the colon)

Comment: the design was like this, the word 'followers' is on top , while the count digit is at the bottom of it, should I enclose the digit with parenthesis  no matter how much the value is ?, or the enclosed digit only applies if the count is located beside the label ?

Comment: Actually, any kind of "separation" will do (a table, one atop another in a dashboard, etc). So you're only getting into all the grammatical trouble in one case — *XX followers.* Anything else works :)

Answer (score 4):

The correct approach in English would be:

- 0 followers
- 1 follower
- 2+ followers

Comment: Correct.  Just to emphasize:  You should pluralize zero.  (You should also pluralize fractions, if for some reason you had 1.5 followers.)